# Put EditText above the soft keyboard

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I am using 2 FrameLayout both have EditText in it, if I click the editText which is at the bottom of the layout can be seen above the softKeyboard but if I click the editBox which frameLayout is above the other FrameLayout place does not change and placed behind the keyboard and the frameLayout which is at the bottom again change its place and it shown above the soft keyboard.

I tried,

```
mMessageBox.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        Commons.logCatchya("onFocusListener changed !");
        if (hasFocus) {
            Commons.logCatchya("onFocusListener hasFocus !");   
        }
        else {
            Commons.logCatchya("onFocusListener do not hav focus !");
        }
    }
});

mMessageBox.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        Commons.logCatchya("setOnKeyListener :" + event.getAction() + " keyCode :" + keyCode);
        return false;
    }
});


mProfileStatusBox.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        Commons.logCatchya("onFocusListener mProfileStatusBox changed !");
        if (hasFocus) {
            Commons.logCatchya("onFocusListener mProfileStatusBox hasFocus !"); 
        }
        else {
            Commons.logCatchya("onFocusListener mProfileStatusBox do not hav focus !");
        }

    }
});
```

but if I click hide soft keyboard button on screen the curser is still on the editbox that I used. Is this problem because of the FrameLayout ? İf not what should I do to solve this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem by using `RelativeLayout` and using

```
android:gravity="bottom"
```

in the layout file.

Answer (score 1):

Set this for your activity tag in your Activity

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
```

if it doesn't worked for you try to set your parent layout in ScrollView

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure you're using `LinearLayout` setting its `width` and `height` to `full_parent`. 

Don't do that, use `RelativeLayout` instead setting the `height` to:
`android:layout_height="wrap_content"`